# Bob Martin: "C has perfect encapsulation" HOW?

Tags: c, oop, encapsulation, software-design

Bob Martin in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMuno5RZNeE) says that "C has perfect encapsulation". I do not understand why he is saying this... I understand that we can separate the implementation in a .c file and declare the interface in a header .h file, but there is nothing really stopping me from accessing implementation details like this:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file1.h"
extern int x;
int main() {
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

file1.c

```
int x = 5;

int getnum_file1() {
    return x + 1;
}
```

file1.h

```
int getnum_file1();
```

In this case, main.c has access to implementation detail in file1.c. This code also compiles and executes with the expected result. How is this perfect encapsulation??

Comment: Just because a language has encapsulation facilities doesn't mean a programmer can't **fail** to encapsulate.

Comment: Because file1 is breaking encapsulation by defining a (potential) global variable?

Comment: c and c++ can be used and abused its really up to the developer to employ good practice.  You can do really nasty things in both languages, even Java lets you do some pretty awful things, for example its perfectly possible to define a static public member variable which is globally accessible.  In your example, remove extern int x, changed x in file1.c to be static.

Comment: Ah I see.. so is the best practice to attach the 'static' keyword to any variable you would like to keep hidden as implementation detail?

Comment: @N.Parikh, static just restricts the variable to the scope it is declared in.

Comment: @SPlatten: that is basically the definition of encapsulation, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to ensure the encapsulation is declaring `x` as `static int x = 5;`, so it won't be visible from an external object (even using `extern`).

Obviously, a global variable as `x` is, can be accessed from another object (via linker, through the `extern` you have added). However, this usually leads to a "spaghetti" code, in which variables are accessed and/or modified from wherever because there is not a proper encapsulation (and C or C++ do provide useful ways to avoid that).